# Label not showing

Tags: wpf, label, show

I'm doing a project in WPF-C# and I put a new label on my project, but it simple doesn't appear when I start debugging, as you can see on the image.
I alredy checked IsEnabled, visibility/opacity, deleting and putting a new one, if the label is in front of the background etc, and everything is ok.
I didn't have this problem with other elementes of the project...
I didn't even wrote the code for it, just put on the grid.
Does anyone know how to fix?

Thanks!

[image: http://i.imgur.com/p5iozfe.jpg]

Comment: Please, when you find your answer post it as an answer to your own question. So it can help other users who have the same/similar problem. =)

Answer (score 1):

Took a while, but after formatting my PC, reinstaling Windows, drivers, programs, etc. The label finally appeared.

I still don't know **exactly** what happened. But this is how I "fixed" it.